# Angular 2 Responsive UI Framework

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to build a responsive web app using angular 2. What I want to achieve is to have a nav bar and a side menu. When the scree is wide, I see the the nav bar and menu. When the screen is small, the side menu hides and the nav bar displays an extra menu icon that drops down or slides from side. I havn't have much success in finding a good framework to help me with it. I thought this might be a common thing that people do with angular 2. Here is an example of what I am looking for. Preferably something that is built for angular 2
[image: large]
[image: small]

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Material 2](https://github.com/angular/material2), which is built by Google specifically for Angular 2 and follows the [material design spec](https://material.io/guidelines/).

For your particular use case you can supplement the framework with [@media css tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to achieve dynamic views based on screen size.